# How to set all elements of linear layout to be same width in android?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

In my android app, I want to create a linear layout of 1 row and 3 columns. Then in each cell, add a new linear layout with 1 column and 2 rows.

Currently it does that, but the width of each of the three cells are wrapping the content, so the overall width of the main linear layout is smaller than the screen width. I want it to match the screen width and then horizontally center the contents of the content of each of the three cells.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

This is the code I have

```
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setWeightSum(1);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);

    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // ---------
    LinearLayout Celllayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    Celllayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    Celllayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView titleView = new TextView(this);
    titleView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    titleView.setText("Use This");

    RadioButton useMapRadio = new RadioButton(this);

    Celllayout.addView(titleView);
    Celllayout.addView(useMapRadio);

    layout.addView(Celllayout);
    // ---------
    Celllayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    Celllayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    Celllayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    titleView = new TextView(this);
    titleView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    titleView.setText(date);

    ImageButton imagebutton = new ImageButton(this);
    imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.calendar);
    imagebutton.setBackgroundResource(0);

    Celllayout.addView(titleView);
    Celllayout.addView(imagebutton);

    layout.addView(Celllayout);
    // ---------
    Celllayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    Celllayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    Celllayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    titleView = new TextView(this);
    titleView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    titleView.setText("Delete");

    imagebutton = new ImageButton(this);
    imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
    imagebutton.setBackgroundResource(0);

    Celllayout.addView(titleView);
    Celllayout.addView(imagebutton);

    layout.addView(Celllayout);
    // ---------

    linearlayout.addView(layout);
```

Comment: Use weigth parametrs.

Comment: Can you show code please, I don't understand.

Comment: i can show you exemple in .xml

Comment: I was hoping for a java example -_-...

Answer (score 2):

This is 3 textView in horizontal layout, the main idea is : width of all items in 
row must be ==0, and weigth for all items must be the same

```
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/start_training"
                    android:textColor="#84d9f4"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/upd_params"
                    android:textColor="#84d9f4"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="df"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But what if you have a linear layout that's horizontal and has 3 cells. What do I set as having weight 1 and width 0?

Comment: If you set width=0, and weigth =1 for all items, all items in row will have the same width.Try it

Answer (score 0):

Use Styles, it works like CSS :: [Styles in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

And yeah, it would be better to make layout's in XML